# How do x86 jump instructions check their respective flags?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, intel

As I understand, conditional jumps check the status of a flag set after the `CMP` instruction. For example:

```
CMP     AX,DX    ; Set compare flags
JGE     DONE     ; Go to DONE label if AX >= DX
...
DONE:
...
```

How are the flags actually checked in this situation? If I'm not mistaken, the flags are individual bits in a special register; so are the bits checked one at a time, or all at once? In C pseudocode:

```c
unsigned flags = 0;    /* reset all flags */

/* define the flags */
const unsigned GREATER = 1<<1;
const unsigned EQUAL = 1<<2;
const unsigned LESS  = 1<<3;

unsigned AX = 4;    /* initialize AX */
unsigned DX = 3;    /* initialize DX */

/* CMP AX,DX */
int result = AX - DX;
if(result > 0){
    flags |= GREATER;
}else if(result == 0){
    flags |= EQUAL;
}else if(result < 0){
    flags |= LESS;
}

/* -------------------------------- */

/* JGE Method 1 */
if(flags & GREATER){
    goto DONE;
}
if(flags & EQUAL){
    goto DONE;
}

/* or JGE Method 2 */
if(flags & (GREATER|EQUAL)){
    goto DONE;
}
```

Don't look to deeply into the flag-setting code -- I know actual x86 processors flags are naturally filled rather than explicitly set -- my concern is how those flags are actually checked: bit by bit, or an encompassing bitmask.

Comment: Well, what it actually does would be buried in the circuitry of the x86 core. It wouldn't work like a procedural language. Probably more like a state language such as VHDL. Someone who has actually worked on an x86 core could probably tell you exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, *it depends*, on how the machine is built.

Let me point you to a PDF of [*Harry Porter's Relay Computer*](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~harry/Relay/RelayTalk.pdf), a particularly simple example of a computer.
Look on slide 115, where he's showing how the instructions are processed.
Basically there's a big blob of combinational logic implementing a Finite State Machine that controls how each instruction is executed.
Most of the stepping in the FSM is concerned with moving data and addresses between registers, using the address and data busses.

If you're wondering what combinational logic is, it is a blob having a bunch of boolean inputs, and a bunch of boolean outputs, and each output is a boolean function of some of the inputs. The blob has no memory. The way it gets memory is by feeding some of the outputs back to the inputs.

So to answer your question, in the context of that computer, it probably tests all the condition bits at the same time, in a boolean expression.

Comment: Since the bits are fed in parallel to the combinational logic, would this mean that each set of bits going through the combinational logic results in the same theoretical latency, regardless of the value of each individual bits?

Comment: @VilhelmGray: Right, because the time spent in the combinational logic is only limited by the depth of the logical expressions and how fast the relays can click. Usually the clock works in, for example, two phases, and at the start of phase 0 the inputs to the combinational logic are assumed valid, and at the end of phase 0 the outputs are assumed to be valid.

Comment: The latency in the combinatorial logic could very well be input-dependent (for example, an "OR" gate may switch low-high faster if both inputs are high, instead of just one).  However, if the machine is designed to be reliable, the latency of the overall operation is that of the synchronous logic framing the combinatorial logic, ie, the results of the combinatorial path are not "used" until sampled at a clock edge which is configured to not happen until after the worst-case combinatorial delay.